# Can't set bollean value to data attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, custom-data-attribute

I have a button with a data attribute:

```
<button id="manageEditContract" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-is-allow-to-edit="@(Model.Contract.IsAllowToEdit)">
       @(Model.Contract.IsAllowToEdit ? "Block" : "Unblock") 
</button>
```

When a user clicks I want the button change its attribute. As my action method returns JSON object with two properties "IsOk" and "IsAllowToEdit", I wrote this function:

```
$('#manageEditContract').on('click', function () {
    var isAllowToEdit = $(this).data('isAllowToEdit');

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ChangeEditOption")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { isAllowToEdit: isAllowToEdit },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.IsOk) {
                $('#manageEditContract').data('isAllowToEdit', JSON.stringify(data.IsAllowToEdit));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But it's not changed.

I tried with JSON.stringify and without it with no luck.

**UPDATED**:
As the answers suggest I should use "attr" to set value to a specific attribute. But I also realized that I should NOT use "data" when I get the value of data attribute as it's the same all the time. looks like "data" attribute caches the data. 
So, instead of

```
var isAllowToEdit = $(this).data('isAllowToEdit');
```

I should use:

```
var isAllowToEdit = $(this).attr('data-isAllowToEdit');
```

Also JSON.stringify is not necessary to use in my case.

Comment: *bollean = boolean

Comment: What is the console output if you do `if (data.IsOk) { console.log(data); }` Does `data.IsAllowToEdit` property exists and has value definied?

Comment: Yeah, it exists. I updated my answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.attr`. This way you don't need to use `JSON.stringify`.

```
var boolValue = true;
$('#manageEditContract').attr('data-is-allow-to-edit', boolValue );
```

See how it works.

```js
var boolValue = true;
$('#manageEditContract').attr('data-is-allow-to-edit', boolValue)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="manageEditContract" data-is-allow-to-edit="false">inspect me</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#manageEditContract').attr('data-is-allow-to-edit', JSON.stringify(data.IsAllowToEdit));
```

That should work